# Looking for the name of a design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, vbscript, garbage-collection, destructor, ephemeron

VBScript guarantees that the GC will run after every line, so if you create an object and don't keep a reference, its destructor will be called at the end of the line. This allows you to do a number of interesting things, one of which is simulating optional arguments:

```
with foo(mandatoryArg)
    .optArg = 42
end
```

Another is allowing for a convenient builder syntax:

```
with Schema.define("Foo")
    .attr "name", String

    with .attr "key", String
        .lengthEquals(10)
    end
end
```

In this example, define and attr return objects that finalize the schema and attribute definitions in the destructor.

I've been calling the temporary object an ephemeron, but I was wondering if there was a preexisting term for such constructions. Anyone seen this elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Builder pattern in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) this is *the* builder or more specifically the concrete builder.  In practice these objects are usually short lived.  The builder pattern has a few components including the director, etc.  But this short lived object you are calling an ephemeron seems to be precisely the builder object.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely using a builder pattern.  The abuse of GC is new, though. The more general name for the type of syntax you're building is a [fluent interface](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).

You could achieve something similar in C# with the "using" syntax, but in practice people use lambda expressions for this, which are more clear.